# Java App’s System Try icon not showing after window login

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java 1.6 SystemTray icon does not appear on windows startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509158/java-1-6-systemtray-icon-does-not-appear-on-windows-startup)

I have java application it creates the system try icon in window OS. When I start manually it run fine. But now I put my application to window startup mean my application should run when window boot without login.

But problem is my application started and perform there tasks but it not adding the system tray icon when some one login.

And even I notice that on window boot up my application is successfully creating the TrayIcon object, creating MenuItem, adding in popup and even adding the tray icon `tray.add(trayIcon);` even no any exception on window bootup, but when I login

It’s not showing on system try along with time, land card icons.

I want that it should create the try icon when some one login same like when we logged in lancard tray icon appears.

Thanks
Regards

Comment: may be this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509158/java-1-6-systemtray-icon-does-not-appear-on-windows-startup

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have a timing problem. You application starts too fast and adds system tray icon before the system tray is created by OS.

Try first to call `SystemTray.getTrayIcons()` and print its output to log. If your icon indeed does not appear in list you are lucky. You can just try to add the icon until it appears in tray.

If it "appears" in list but you cannot see it try the following. 
Add some delay before you are adding system tray. If it will help add thread that updates system try periodically. It is not so nice solution but it will work anyway even if user restarts his desktop (I am not sure it is possible in windows but it definitely possible on linux).